# Sequelize Migrations: No association gets added

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I migrated my models, then I added associations, but now when I enter the command `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate` My associations don't get added, is this the correct way to do it? Thank you

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Role = sequelize.define('Role', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
      timestamps: false
  });
  Role.associate = function(models) {
      // associations can be defined here
      Role.belongsToMany(models.Resource, {through: models.Permission, foreignKey: 'role_id'})
  };
  return Role;
};
```

**Or is it normal in phpmyadmin I don't see the fk relations when I click on a structure of a table?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have migrations for all your models without associations (i.e. foreign  keys for tables) then you you create migrations for creating foreign keys.
An example from Sequelize API:

```
queryInterface.addConstraint('Posts', ['username'], {
  type: 'foreign key',
  name: 'custom_fkey_constraint_name',
  references: { //Required field
    table: 'target_table_name',
    field: 'target_column_name'
  },
  onDelete: 'cascade',
  onUpdate: 'cascade'
});
```